# Can't create Dataframe from RDD in Spark / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql

I'm runin into issue creating a Dataframe, getting overloaded method value....

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}

val schemaString = "prediction"

val schema = StructType(schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName ⇒ StructField(fieldName, DoubleType, true)))

val preds = predictions.select("probability").rdd.map(row => 
      (row.getAs[Vector](0).toString)).first.split(",").map(_.trim replaceAll ("[\\[\\]\"]", "")).map(_.toDouble).zipWithIndex

val sortedPreds = preds.sortBy(_._1).reverse

val doubles = sortedPreds map { case (score, toolIndex) =>  toolIndex.toDouble }

// case class myRow(i: Double, j: Double, k: Double, m: Double, z: Double)

val queryRDDRow = sc.parallelize(Seq(doubles))
val predDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(queryRDDRow, schema)
```

Comment: Can you post a reproducible code ? (where did you define predRDD ?)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `createDataFrame(queryRDDRow, schema)` ?

Comment: Apologies, have updated now

Comment: What's the purpose of parallelizing a sequence of **one** array ?

Comment: I need this array of Doubles as a dataframe so I can use an IndexToString model

Comment: but it's just one entry. I think what you need is to transform that array into an sequence